# Unable to set innerHTML property with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-traversal

I want to set the text of a `p` element using Javascript. What can I do to fix my error and properly set the text? Why am I getting this error?

When I execute `generate()` by clicking on the html button from this line of code in my html file,

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate!" onclick="generate()">
```

I get the following error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Below is my generate() function in my referenced javascript randomizer.js file.

```
function generate() {
  var team = document.getElementById('template').cloneNode(true)
  console.log('queryselector', team.querySelectorAll('p')[0].innerHTML)
  team.querySelectorAll('p')[0].innerHTML = "ah hah!";
}
```

Here are a few other considerations and notes:

1. My Javascript file is referenced near the very end of my html document like so:

...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='randomizer.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. The output of `queryselector` of my `console.log` statement is defined and properly shows the current text inside the `p` element. So, it is strange that when I try to set it, it suggests that `team` is null.

Comment: it doesn't suggest team is null, it suggests `team.querySelectorAll('p')[0]` is null - but, the code looks like it should work - which browser are you using?

Comment: You're aware that you're working with a clone, and not the elements in the DOM ?

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I'm using Chrome. adeneo, yes I'm aware that I've cloned it but shouldn't you still be able to manipulate that node even though it isn't connected to the HTML DOM yet? Why is it that I am able to read the property then in console.log?

Answer (score 0):

My code seems to work as intended now. Unfortunately I do now know exactly why. I left my computer and browser on and when I got back I noticed two error messages in the console but was unable to read them as I have already clicked refresh. I think for the time being I have to brush this off as some odd browser issue or may have been some lines of code I had inserted after this(not shown). Thanks everyone.